# Cannot add ESXi installation disk to datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi

My server has 2 hard drives: 1xSSD and 1xHDD.

ESXi is installed on the SSD.

HDD is added as the datastore.

I can't find a way to add the SSD as a datastore too.

Here I see it:

[image]

But when I click on "New datastore" and give it a name, I reach here:

[image]

The problem is I can't select any partition here so I tried to edit partitions and delete that big VMFSL (111GB) but it failed too.

What I'm missing?

Comment: It's been a while since I installed an ESXi with local storage, but IIRC the installation disk is always added as a datastore by default. Have you checked if it isn't there already?

Comment: Yes I am. I see it in the "Devices" tab but not in the "Datastores" tab and I can't add it. Reinstalled ESXi but same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too small SSD drive to create datastore, only 120GB. ESXi 7.0 uses the whole capacity for ESX-OSData (VMFSL), so all free space is occupied. Here is reference - https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.esxi.upgrade.doc/GUID-DEB8086A-306B-4239-BF76-E354679202FC.html